# How to Copy Paste Value in Column U cell based on input made in Column C

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As a default Column B is equal to Column U. I'd like to find a macro that copies the value in Column U (e.g. U2) and pastes it as a value in the same cell (U2) if a value is inputted into cell C3 (one row below the U2 cell). Please see the example below, where if I enter GHI123 in cell C3, CD must be copied and pasted in cell U2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZFh8IW6SLkOxNBSyUaDapOnMm2cJwxjZ7KFA79MKnw/edit#gid=0

Comment: basically this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C1:C), B1:B, ))` via script

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following Apps Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();

  if (column == 3){
    cellToEdit = 'U' + (row - 1);
    dataToPaste = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellToEdit).getDisplayValue()
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellToEdit).setValue(dataToPaste);

}
```

The `getDisplayValue()` method allows you to read the displayed value of a cell after any script evaluation. You can find the reference for this method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()).